# Corona SDK: Get file size of JSON file to be downloaded

Tags: lua, http-headers, progress-bar, coronasdk

Using Corona SDK, I would like to get the file size of a JSON file that I am downloading from my server.

Is there any way to scan the HTTP header in Corona, so that I know the size of the file, before the download completes? In that case, how?

Also, how can I find out how many KBs of a file that is currently successfully downloaded.

FYI, I am trying to implement a download progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is usually not possible when dealing with json (and other non-binary files)

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html#download-file-with-progress-updates